# Running program twice with same conditions yields different outputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a little program to model the orbit of the earth around the sun.  It is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NBvPp/

Running it with dx=0 and dy=4 yields very different orbits on different runs, even when the planet doesn't get close to the center of the sun.

Any ideas why?  Is the computer handling roundoff error differently each time or what?

Comment: Your fiddle is completely broken... please take a moment and make yourself familiar with jsfiddle before you use it. Otherwise it's not going to be much of a help for us.

Comment: Ok... it's not "completely" broken, but the JavaScript field contains HTML, which is why you see `});//]]>` in the output. And you are including Mootools instead of jQuery (which you include manually) which does not seems to be a problem, but could be one. It just makes it more difficult to work with... and I'm actually surprised that the script runs.

Comment: I mostly don't care about the particulars of the code - just theoretically how could the same code, run multiple times, generate different behavior?  I thought the computer just executes the same commands in a completely determined fashion.

Comment: I don't know, it always seems to behave the same way to me... how do you determine differences?

Comment: If you let it run for about a minute you will see different long term behavior in the orbit.  Sometimes you get a very tight orbit which is actually "inside" the sun, other times the orbit is larger.  Sometimes it enters a stable orbit very quickly, and other times it takes a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't reset the "r" variable after restarting the execution, I've added

```
r = Math.pow(Math.pow(x-WIDTH/2,2)+Math.pow(y-HEIGHT/2,2),.5)
```

to the startdraw() function:

http://jsfiddle.net/NBvPp/1/

Comment: Awesome!  That was really bugging me...

Comment: You're welcome, usually when the second execution without refreshing the page behaves diferently it's a global variable (or because a Math.random() obviously) :)